# Difference between "Fine by me." and "It is fine with me."

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

I learned this idiom "Fine by me." recently. I also read another webpage [**This is fine with / by / for me**](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-is-fine-with-by-for-me.180564/). So I wondered whether there was any difference between them.

> "It is fine **with** me."

I looked up OALD.

I guessed that the meaning of the word "**with**" is of #7

[7, used when considering one fact in relation to another](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/with?q=with)

Though #6 was a possible choice at first for me.

> Fine **by** me

What is the meaning of the word "**by**" here?

> What is the difference between "Fine **by** me." and "It is fine **with** me." in terms of meaning or usage?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Because these are idioms, I would not expect to be able to make the words _by_ and _with_ fit the meanings of the idiom. According to [this entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Fine+By+Me), the two expressions are equivalent in meaning. This is also how I feel about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reference, @Max. I learned this idiom "Fine _by_ me." recently. I also read another webpage. [This is fine with / by / for me](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-is-fine-with-by-for-me.180564/) So I wondered whether there was any difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fine with me" and "fine by me" do indeed mean the same thing. As Max said, they are both idioms. My sense is that the first version is better established and the second is a little more informal, although neither is really very formal.

Interestingly, "I am fine with it" also means the same thing.

Comment: "**I** am fine with _it_"  VS “_It_ is fine with **me**” Wow. It looks interesting. Thanks.